# JavaScript/jQuery - offsetLeft and offsetTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

When hovering over a span I would like to get the offsetLeft and offsetTop values so I can make something hover near it. When I do this I get 0 for both values.

What is a better way to tackle this? I am using jQuery.

Assume I am starting with (looped by server-side scripting):

```
<span onmouseover="hoverNearMe(this.offsetLeft,this.offsetTop);">some username</span><br />
```

**FINAL THOUGHTS:**
I'm giving the the answer rep out based on "code leverage"/DRY.
The longer function you could use over and over in your own js library.
The second short answer however is 100% correct too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this:

**HTML**

```
<span class="get-close-to">some username</span><br />
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('.get-close-to').hover(function() {
    var offset = jQuery(this).css('offset');
    alert( 'Left: ' + offset.left + '\nTop: ' + offset.top );
});
```

Comment: does this handle the whole "cumulative" offset thing?

Comment: @Bruno - I think it should.  It gets the offset relative to the document.

Answer (score 28):

`$(this).offset().left` and `$(this).offset().top`

Comment: Be careful, $(this).offset().left is not equivalent to this.offsetLeft (same for top). http://jsfiddle.net/gnNLD/5/

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need server-side scripting?

try this:

```
    var positionImg = function(e) {
        $(this).offset();
    var zoomCntnrPos = $(this).offset.top;
      if (zoomCntnrPos >= maxBottomVPos)
      {
           tPosX = e.pageX;
           tPosY = e.pageY +20;
          }
      else if (zoomCntnrPos <= maxTopVPos){
           tPosX = e.pageX;
           tPosY = e.pageY +40;
          }
      else
          {
           tPosX = e.pageX;
           tPosY = e.pageY -100;  
          }
        $zoomContainer.css({top: tPosY, left: tPosX});
    };
```

Comment: So you never use server-side? PHP even? Can you explain your code? seems a little bloated.

Comment: this is just part of the code. here you are positioning the hover via javaScript and position via the mousemove event event.pageX and event.pageY.